# Retrieve Multiple values from same Input tag using Java

Tags: java, html, json

I'm having problem retrieving multiple values from the input tag. Im retrieving the value from a JSONArray file.

Under my post method, how am I able to retrieve more than 1 values from the input tag and store inside a JSONArray variable?

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%; max-width: none;">
  <!-- values are the data inside the JSON Array -->
  <c:forEach items="${values}" var="val" varStatus="count">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class=" form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <!-- //for example, the for loop generate 2 input tag -->
            <input type="text" name="fruit" id="fruit" value="${val.fruit}">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I'm only able to retrieve just one of the values by doing this,

```java
String apple = request.getParameter("fruit");

JSONObject newOutput = new JSONObject();
newOutput.put("fruit", apple);
JSONArray arr_Output = new JSONArray();
arr_Output.add(newOutput);
```

I expect to read more than 1 input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.getParameterMap().get("fruit")` in your `POST` method, it will return a string array with all values.